# Visual Studio 2012, how to configure symbols for debugging on an offline environment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols

I've just started using VS2012 in an offline environment for development and I couldnt run my program as it is always saying it cant find / open the PDB files for the windows dlls

After some researching, I saw most of the solutions requires them to download symbols from the microsoft server. Or download the symbols manually. But with no detail instruction of how to link the offline symbol package to the debugger.

After installing the msi (into C:\Symbols) and pointing C:\Symbols in the debugging > symbols > location / setting the cache folder to point to C:\Symbols. Both attempt did not work.

May I know what I'm doing wrongly ?

Comment: Symbol packages made sense in the previous century, back when Internet connection speeds were very slow and Microsoft wasn't yet forced to deliver frequent updates to keep the malware at bay.  They just don't work anymore, the odds for a version mismatch are way to large.  You'll need to drag the machine to an Internet connection and prime the symbol cache.  Or, perhaps, not focus too much on operating system bugs.  It is never an OS bug, just make sure you have good PDBs for your own code.

Comment: I wish it could be as easy as hooking it up with an internet connection.

The problem is the application is always forced to close in debug mode as it complains that it couldnt find the window dll's PDB files

Comment: It is just a diagnostic message, not an error message.